# jQuery (with CoffeeScript) cloning a link and activating behind-the-scenes

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, dialog

Building out a custom confirm dialog by attaching a `click` event handler to a link via `data-custom-confirm` attribute.  I'm trying to implement a maintainable solution using objects in CoffeeScript, something I haven't done a lot of.

**Question:**
It seems there has to be a cleaner way of implementing this than cloning links, hiding them, and firing their `click` event behind-the-scenes?

My thoughts are:

1. When original link is clicked, create the Dialog with a clone of the link that removes the `data-custom-confirm` that overrides the click event.
2. When the `confirm` button is clicked in dialog, fire the `click` event for the cloned link behind-the-scenes.
3. Using a cloned link allows me to maintain events already attached to the original link so that I don't completely remove those.

I do use Handlebars for JS templating, but threw the HTML inline here for the sake of this question.

`<a href="url" data-custom-confirm="confirm msg">Text</a>`

Event handler for activating link

```
$("a[data-custom-confirm]").on "click", ->
  template = $("<div class='dialog'>
    <div class='dialog-title'>Title</div>
    <div class='dialog-content'>Content...</div>
    <div class='dialog-actions'>
      <button type='button' role='confirm'>Confirm</button>
      <button type='button' role='cancel'>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>")
  new Dialog(template, $(this))
```

Dialog CoffeeScript class

```
class @Dialog
  DIALOGS: []
  @destroyAll: ->
    dialog.destroy() for dialog in Dialog::DIALOGS
    @DIALOGS = []

  constructor: (element, triggerLink) ->
    @element = $(element) # DIV.dialog
    @triggerLink = $(triggerLink) # Link that activated dialog
    @triggerLinkClone = @triggerLink.clone().removeAttr("data-confirm-dialog")
    @create()
    @.setEvents()

  setEvents: ->
    @element.find("[role='cancel']").on "click", =>
      @destroy()

    @element.find("[role='confirm']").on "click", =>
      # Is this the best way to implement this?
      @element.append(@triggerLinkClone)
      @triggerLinkClone.hide().click()

  create: ->
    $("body").append(@element)
    @DIALOGS.push(this)
    @element.fadeIn("fast")

  destroy: ->
    @element.remove()     # Remove from DOM
    @DIALOGS.remove(this) # Remove from JS memory
```